# Borrar una entidad hija sin borrar la entidad padre en Hibernate - Java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate

estoy tratando de borrar una entidad hija en Hibernate, sin borrar la entidad padre. Solo tengo 2 tablas (relación 1 a 1 bidireccional) en mi base de datos (postgresql) con la siguiente estructura:

[image: Tabla clientes]
Esta seria la tabla clientes

[image: Tabla clientes_detalles]
Esta seria la tabla clientes_detalles

La tabla clientes detalles tiene una llave foránea, que es la columna cliente_id, se refiera a la columna id de la tabla clientes.

En hibernate yo puedo crear un cliente, luego crear el detalle de ese cliente. Luego borrar el cliente y automáticamente por la cascada se borra el detalle de ese cliente.

Pero si trato de borrar el detalle de un cliente, únicamente el detalle del cliente (sin borrar al cliente), no tengo éxito, se borra el cliente también, y no es el comportamiento esperado.

Mi clase Cliente.java tiene la asociación y luce así:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="cliente", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private ClienteDetalle clienteDetalle;
```

Mi clase ClienteDetalle.java tiene la asociación y luce así:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="cliente_id")
private Cliente cliente;
```

La forma como estoy tratando de borrar al detalle del cliente es así:

```
ClienteDetalle clienteDetalleBorrar = miSession.get(ClienteDetalle.class, UN_ID_DE_ALGUNA_FILA_EN_CLIENTES_DETALLES);
miSession.delete(clienteDetalleBorrar);
```

Al hacerlo se sucede esto:

[image: Se borra el cliente y el detalle]

Cuando únicamente quiero que se borre el detalle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que definiste que al atributo `cliente` se le apliquen TODAS las operaciones en cascada (`cascade=CascadeType.ALL`). Por este motivo cuando eliminas el detalle también se elimina el cliente asociado.

Para corregir esto debes reemplazar el `CascadeType.ALL` por aquellos que necesites, ej.:

```
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="cliente_id")
private Cliente cliente;
```

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error al tratar de eliminar el detalle (luego de aplicar los cambios que sugeriste):

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [es.darioxlz.conexionHibernate.ClienteDetalle#10]

Comment: @darioxlz estás borrando los detalles sin indicarle al cliente que ahora no va a tener detalles. O sea, algo como esto: `cliente.setClienteDetalle(null)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió, creo que si usara HQL pudiese hacer "delete from ClienteDetalle where Cliente.id = 10" podría hacer lo que quiero sin tener que setear el clienteDetalle a null en el objeto cliente, cierto?

Comment: @darioxlz lo que pasa es que no debes perder de vista que entre la base de datos y tú lógica de negocio está el *EntityManager* y este mantiene las entidades cargadas en *cache*, por lo que aunque elimines el detalle usando una consulta vas a tener que indicar que el cliente asociado ya no va a tener una detalle. de lo contrario el framework detecta que estás eliminando una entidad vinculada a otra.

Comment: ah claro, entiendo, es bueno setearlo a null, para que el ORM sepa que ya no existe, no tiene sentido borrarlo directo en la base de datos mientras que el ORM no sabe que lo borraste

Comment: @darioxlz exacto, algo así.